# How can I convert an Excel file on a Linux server to a delimited text file?

Tags: linux, excel, csv, export

I am running a Linux server and one of our suppliers only knows how to send me an Excel file which I need to import into our system daily.  Does anyone know of a good way to export the Excel file to a delimited file?  Preferably with php or perl.

Thanks!

Chris Edwards

Comment: Ubuntu has packages `libspreadsheet-parseexcel-perl`, `libspreadsheet-parseexcel-simple-perl`, `libspreadsheet-ruby`, `libspreadsheet-xlsx-perl`, `python-excelerator`, `python-xlrd`, `python-xlwt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java library POI does this quite well, with very simple API.

http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice (or LibreOffice) has a scripting ability, alas, which I have never looked at.  However, it seems it would be straightforward to open the Excel file using Calc, and then do a Save As .csv operation.

Comment: Seems like a horrible thing to do daily. :)

Comment: In the meantime, the supplier can be *re-educated*. Maybe they could learn how to send CSV files.

Comment: @sarnold:  Surely having the computer do the work is far superior to having a human do it.  Also, such a low volume conversion is a poor choice of engineering time, since what's the difference if it performs the conversion in seconds instead of minutes?

Comment: good point about minutes vs seconds, but I know I wouldn't be keen on having OpenOffice or LibreOffice installed on my servers when a Perl module would probably suffice.

Comment: @sarnold:  does it actually have to be installed on the server?  A `cron` job on any computer with sufficient access to the server would be good enough, like through `scp`.